# Webpack 5 warning: 'require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.'

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I know this is a fairly common question but I haven't been able to crack it yet.

I'm upgrading a project to Webpack5 and I'm trying to get rid of these three warnings. Is there a something I can add to my `resolve:{}` object? I'm not sure what loaders I would use or how to add them to my webpack.config.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/interpret/index.js 78:6-24
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/index.js 11:15-35
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/logger.js 1:14-32
 @ ./js/components/global.js 2:0-51
 @ ./js/index.js 4:0-29

WARNING in ./node_modules/rechoir/index.js 21:18-36
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/index.js 15:15-33
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/logger.js 1:14-32
 @ ./js/components/global.js 2:0-51
 @ ./js/index.js 4:0-29

WARNING in ./node_modules/rechoir/lib/register.js 7:13-32
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/rechoir/index.js 5:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/index.js 15:15-33
 @ ./node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/logger.js 1:14-32
 @ ./js/components/global.js 2:0-51
 @ ./js/index.js 4:0-29
```